# There is some error in try and except block in my Python code. unable to fix it

Tags: python

This program takes four delimited numbers as user input ,performs calculation on them and prints the output. experiencing trouble with error handling with try and except

This is my code

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter four delimited numbers separated by a comma (e.g., 1,2,3,4): ")
    user_num = user_input.split(',')  # list of numbers

    try:
        if len(user_num) == 4:
            user_data = [float(e) for e in user_num]  # converts string input to float
            num_one = float(user_num[0])  # assigning to variables
            num_two = float(user_num[1])
            num_three = float(user_num[2])
            num_four = float(user_num[3])
            user_result = ((num_one * num_two) + num_three) / num_four # store result of calculations
            print(f'{num_one} * {num_two} + {num_three} / {num_four} = {user_result}')
            exit() #break
        else:
            continue

    
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Invalid input. Please enter valid numbers separated by commas.")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Error: The fourth number entered is zero. Cannot divide by zero. Enter a valid number.")
    except IndexError:
        print("Error: Please enter four delimited numbers ")
```

My problem is that the ValueError and IndexError  blocks are working but the index error is not working. for example, if I put 3 numbers instead of 4 like 1,2,3 it prints `Please enter four delimited numbers separated by a comma (e.g., 1,2,3,4):` it does not print the error message that `Error: Please enter four delimited numbers`. the same thing for value error, if I enter 1234 instead of 1,2,3,4 it does not display error message

Comment: `if len(user_num) == 4:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. It seems like you should learn [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For more tips, check out [ask]. That said, Joe seems to have found the problem.

Comment: The input `1234` doesn't generate a `ValueError` because `[float(e) for e in user_num]` will parse it. If you need `1234` to generate a `ValueError`, you can test for the presence of commas with a conditional expression. There are multiple bugs in this code and multiple questions here. Please do some debugging and edit the question to address one, specific problem. This will increase the quality of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the following conditional guard, `IndexError` is never raised.

```
if len(user_num) == 4:
```

If you remove this and allow the loop to *assume* there are four values in the list, but there aren't, then an `IndexError` will be raised and handled.

Comment: i cant remove it. we are have to use conditional block

Comment: @Deepika Then this code can never have an IndexError.

Comment: Please enter four delimited numbers separated by a comma (e.g., 1,2,3,4): 1234
Error: Please enter four delimited numbers. it also shows an error in value error. it should print an error enter numbers separated by comma

Comment: @Deepika Replace *continue* with an error message indicating that the wrong number of values were input

Comment: The program asks us to check for index error, zero division and value error in single conditional block. I want to raise error message for values not separated by comma if I enter 1234 instead of 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question will not induce IndexError because the indexing has effectively been pre-validated by checking the length of the *user_num* list.

You don't actually need to check the list length. In fact, you don't need a discrete list at all.

```
while True:
    user_num = input("Please enter four delimited numbers separated by a comma (e.g., 1,2,3,4): ")
    try:
        a, b, c, d = map(float, user_num.split(','))
        print(f'({a} * {b} + {c}) / {d} = {(a * b + c) / d}')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Invalid input. Please enter valid numbers separated by commas.")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Error: The fourth number entered is zero. Cannot divide by zero. Enter a valid number.")
```

In this code, we [try to] unpack the *map()* output to 4 variables. If there are not exactly 4 elements then the unpacking will result in a ValueError as will any failed attempt to convert a token to float

Comment: you are right. it asks us to validate the user input and check for index error. if we validate user input, the index error won't be raised